# Anonymous posting facebook comments?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

Based on this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ people can post using other third party services, but can users post anonymously on a web-site using FB comment system?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is impossible to post anonymously using Facebook's comment system. Whatever the website, your comment will be associated to your facebook profile, if you are commenting using the facebook log in.