# Remove website name from Facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I've thoroughly looked for this everywhere but I've not found a solution. Forgive me if I wasn't thorough enough and that there is a post like this before.

Anyway, here's my issue:

I'm trying to remove my website name 'Posts For You' from the sharing name when I share a post from my website to Facebook. See the image below, whatever is in the red box, I want it not to be there by default. I want every post to be shared with just the post title and not including the website name before the title.

[Please see this image. - This is what I want removed by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OynYY.png)

Comment: I think it is impossible. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463718/anonymous-posting-facebook-comments

Comment: Do you have any code to share with us that illustrates what you are doing?

Comment: What URL are you sharing?

Comment: I purchased this template, I did not design it myself.

Comment: This is the URL I'm sharing : https://postsforyou.com/list/why-youd-rather-have-an-iphone